# Scraping data from json which is in "2nd line"

Tags: python, json, screen-scraping

Good evening,

I want to scrape the testid. What I tried and which isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
Json = json.loads(info.content)
aba = Json['checkout']['line_items'].get("testid")
```

```
infocontent = 
{
   "checkout":{
      "completed_at":null,
      "created_at":"2020-02-27T17:43:50+01:00",
      "line_items":[
         {
            "id":"538af6bda25ea2ba30811ca527631cc6",
            "key":"538af6bda25ea2ba30811ca527631cc6",
            "auth":4462126596176,
            "testid":31830643277904,
          }]
}
```

Comment: The value of `line_items` is a list so you should either iterate through it or use an index to access the subdicts within.

Comment: Note:using python terminology because I know it better than json. `line_items` is a list of dictionaries. There is only one dictionary. So simply before the `.get(` part of your code add `[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `line_items` is a list of objects, albeit there is only one object in the list. You need to get the first item in the list before you can use `get` on it.

```
aba = Json['checkout']['line_items'][0].get("testid")
```